# Squid limit total bandwidth per user

Tags: squid, bandwidth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Squid Proxy Server: limit total bandwidth](https://serverfault.com/questions/209158/squid-proxy-server-limit-total-bandwidth)

Is there any feature of squid to limit the total bandwidth for every user?

Comment: or this:  http://serverfault.com/questions/79824/limiting-bandwidth-dynamically-in-squid

Comment: There isn't a duplicate. I want to limit per user the bandwidth

Answer (score 0):

http://www.howtoforge.com/squid-delay-pools-bandwidth-management

[Limit total bandwidth use per user](https://serverfault.com/questions/8439/limit-total-bandwidth-use-per-user)

try above links :)